# Styling the "show details" area of an Alert in JavaFX

Tags: java, css, javafx, dialog, alert

How can I style the marked area of an `Alert`'s `Dialog` using CSS? Please help.

[image: Alert Image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Modena.css styling for `Alert` is available [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u40/rt/file/6cc08ec1ea82/modules/controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css) from ~ line 3339

For the details button the selectors of interest would be:

```
.dialog-pane > .button-bar > .container > .details-button {
  -fx-alignment: baseline-left;
  -fx-focus-traversable: false;
  -fx-padding: 0.416em; /* 5px */
}

.dialog-pane > .button-bar > .container > .details-button.more {
    -fx-graphic: url("dialog-more-details.png");
}

.dialog-pane > .button-bar > .container > .details-button.less {
    -fx-graphic: url("dialog-fewer-details.png");
}

.dialog-pane > .button-bar > .container > .details-button:hover {
    -fx-underline: true;
}
```

---

Example:

CSS:

```
.dialog-pane > .button-bar > .container > .details-button.more {
    -fx-background-color: red;
}

.dialog-pane > .button-bar > .container > .details-button.less {
    -fx-background-color: green;
}
```

[image]
[image]

---

Update:

You can also change the image by modifying the `-fx-graphic`, but the image must be of the dimensions you want. The below images use a 24 x 24 icon

CSS:

```
.dialog-pane > .button-bar > .container > .details-button.more {
    -fx-graphic: url("unchecked_checkbox.png");
}

.dialog-pane > .button-bar > .container > .details-button.less {
    -fx-graphic: url("checked_checkbox.png");
}
```

[image: un-marked checkbox]
[image: marked checkbox]

Comment: Thabks a lot for your answer. It works like a charm! Can i change the button to a checkbox?

Comment: But the text will be changed. How to fix that?

Comment: Thanks for elaboration. But I've managed to do that before your edit. What I'm asking is when we click a checkbox it's textProperty doesn't change.  here the box image is changing as well as the text. I want the text remain "Show details" and the image tell the user it's active state.

Comment: @Subhranil so you want it to always be a marked checkbox with "Show details" regardless of whether the dialog pane is expanded?

Comment: Nope. I want the text "show details" remain same and the image change. That's what the checkboxes do. Let's say the text "show details" is positive, "hide details" is negative. Marked checkbox is positive and unmarked is negative. Then you can see any of the following pairs of "marked checkbox+hide details" and "unmarked checkbox + show details " has the same value. I.e. the state is not literally changing.